# Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV) working in MacOS chrome but does not work in Windows

Tags: html, reactjs, input-type-file

I have an `<input>` tag which i am using for uploading the .csv files. It looks like it works totally ok in my Mac OS chrome and other browsers but the same allows all the other files that can be uploaded in Windows.

```jsx
<input
  type="file" 
  id="fileElem"
  accept=".csv"
  style={{ display: 'none' }}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Any leads where am I going wrong?

Comment: What Windows browsers and versions are you using? You can see the compatibility chart here ~ https://caniuse.com/input-file-accept

Comment: chrome 99 and the person in windows using the same.